# How do I get information from a JSON file a certain amount at a time for Angular 6 project?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, pagination

I'm creating a search engine for science articles with Angular 6 and I need to add pagination. 
This is my search function

```
search() {
    var query: string = window.location.search.substring(1).split("=")[1];
    this.http
      .get(
        "http://my.json/_search?q=" +
          query +
          "&size=100"
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.response = response;
      });
  }
```

So at the moment I'm only retrieving 100 articles. The database currently has a little over 15,000 articles so I'm limiting the amount of articles I'm receiving once the page is loaded. I can easily just put `&size=15000` for the worst case scenario but this takes the page a very long time to load. Is there a way to load a few articles at a time, lets say 10, and then every time I move to another page, another 10 are pulled from the JSON?

I'm also currently using this for pagination

```
<div *ngFor="let hit of response.hits.hits | orderBy: key : true | paginate: { itemsPerPage:6, currentPage: p} let i = index">
    <!--HTML Code in here-->
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p =$event"></pagination-controls>
```

Comment: how about using a virtual scroll library?

Comment: I don't know how a virtual scroll works but I assume that it would need all the data to perform the loading effect right? Because what I don't know how to do is load a certain amount of data from the JSON at a time. Does the virtual scroll do that for me?

Comment: A virtual scroll only displays a subset of the array you want to show at a time. This will help if you are having UI issues like stuttering or slow loading. But if the API itself is taking a long time to load then you should probably implement pagination on the API itself

Comment: yeah that is essentially what I'm trying to do. any tips or links that you are aware of?

Comment: @BryanBastida I doubt anyone would have any tips or tricks regarding pagination here if you don't A. give more details about the API you're using and B. create a completely new question regarding said topic.

Answer (score 0):

@BryanBastida, sure. In general , you only need two things in your server:

1.-a function that return the numbers of articles (it's necesary to make a pagination)

2.-That a function that return the next 10 items greater that a "key". Just in Angular store in an array the "keys" of each page.

```
   /*If your page=0 show 1,2,5,6,9 and page=1 show 10,12,15,16,17
    lastItem[0]=9, lastItem[1]=17;
   */
    lastItem:any[]=[];
    //Each change of page
    changePage(page)
    {
       let firstItem=page==0?:null:(firstItem.length<page-1)?firstItem[page-1]:lastItem;
       get("myUrl?firstItem=firstItem).subscribe(res=>{
         if (res)
         {
            lastItem[page]=res[res.length-1].key
            this.data=res;
         }
       )
     }
```